# Where fieldname is null using active record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I tried

```
$this->db->where('fieldname IS NULL',  false);
```

and this gives me

```
WHERE `fieldname` IS NULL 0
```

causing an error.
Can't understand where the 0 comes from. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second parameter should be NULL, not FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this

```
$this->db->where('fieldname =','');
```

Or

```
$this->db->where('fieldname IS NULL');
```